# Question about process race conditions on system calls

Tags: c, operating-system, filesystems, system-calls, mmap

When you use `mmap` with `MAP_PRIVATE` on a file:

> It is unspecified whether changes made to the file
> after the mmap() call are visible in the mapped region

Does this mean that if you are mid-read, another process may alter the region and you may get garbage data?

It seems to me that `write` and `read` syscalls provide some protections against this, in that it would be atomic, but `mmap` if you are reading say 4 KiB, that chunk may get altered, and perhaps even creates problems for the readers.

Another thing that I have thought is that the library functions operating on `FILE*` may not always show the latest data because they are buffered.

Answer (score 0):

The manual says that the behavior is unspecified, so anything could be possible in this case and I wouldn't rely on any specific observed behavior since the behavior could change in the future. That being said, here is what is likely happening:

First, let's assume the `MAP_PRIVATE` flag is not set. The atomic guarantee provided by `write()` does not hold when reading via an mmap'd memory region. The `write()` syscall writes data to the physical frame backing the mmap'd region, so if process A reads the mmap'd region in parallel, it may see a partial write. On the other hand, if A were reading the file via the `read()` syscall, the `write()` would appear to be atomic because there is locking in the kernel filesystem.

Now let's focus on the `MAP_PRIVATE` case. The likely reason why the manual says the behavior is unspecified is because the behavior will depend on whether process A has written to a particular page in the mmap'd region already. When `MAP_PRIVATE` is specified, the OS employs the copy-on-write mechanism for the mmap'd region. Thus, the mmap'd region is initially mapped to the same physical frames that `write()` writes to, but upon a write by process A to a page in the mmap'd region, the file data is copied to a new physical frame and the page is remapped to this new physical frame.

Therefore, if process A has not yet written the page, the contents of the `write()` by process B will be visible (either partially or fully) when process A reads the page. If process A has already written the page, the contents of the `write()` by process B will not be visible when process A reads the page, since the page is mapped to a new physical frame.

Comment: That's what I figured. So really the `MAP_PRIVATE` for files does not create truly private memory (at least at first), due to the nature of copy-on-write.

Comment: @user129393192 You are correct. If you need private mappings, you could store to every page in the mmap'd region immediately after creation. You could also look into `UFFDIO_REGISTER_MODE_MINOR` from userfaultfd, though that may not be a fit for your case.

Comment: Understood. Interestingly enough, I am seriously struggling to see the benefit of `mmap`, since from my understanding, the `read` and `write` interface is heavily optimized (at least on Linux), and it seems to me that an `mmap`'d file produces similar race conditions as to running `fsck` while a file system is mounted ... not sure I see the use case. I even spoke to one of the maintainers of `grep` on this and he said that it actually made their application run slower ...

Comment: @user129393192 Within the context of accessing files, I'd say there are pros and cons to each of mmap and the file system syscalls. mmap makes it easier to do random accesses, avoids copying between userspace and the kernel, and allows processes to communicate via shared memory (particularly useful for atomics, umonitor/umwait, etc.). You can also pin mmap'd pages to memory with mlock(). On the other hand, read()/write() provide certain synchronization guarantees to you. So it really comes down to what performance you need and which abstraction you find more desirable.